# Issue with async Task<T> in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, task

I'm trying to use the Azure media services with REST api, in a xamarin shared project on visual studio 2013. This is the code i use to get the access token.

```
public HttpFactory()
{
    string token = GetToken(serviceURI).Result;
    //some more methods also async tasks
}

private async Task<string> GetToken(Uri serviceUri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceURI);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers["Host"] = "media.windows.net";
    request.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2.9";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
    {
        serviceURI = new Uri(response.Headers["Location"]);
        HttpWebRequest req = ( HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceURI);
        var res = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync();

        using (Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
                JToken jtoken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(str);
                 return jtoken["access_token"].Value<string>();

            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

But when the compiler reaches -

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

it skips the rest of the code, and i never get the response. I know the code is working - because it works just fine without the task, in a async void method.

Anyone knows how to fix this, or am i doing something wrong? I also tried this in vs2015 but its the same.

Comment: Tip: I'd consider using `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` - it's a higher level abstraction, and it often avoids having to handle streams.

Comment: I like to, but the code im writing are supposed to be translated into java by another developer - and im not supposed to use code that cant be used in java - or easily translated atleast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a deadlock over the UI thread.

You're blocking the thread with `Task.Result` when it is needed to complete the async method which will complete the task that it's waiting on.

That's why you shouldn't block synchronously on asynchronous code. You should await the task returned from `GetToken` instead:

```
string token = await GetToken(serviceURI);
```

If you can't use async in that method, either move that logic to a different method (e.g. `OnLoad` event handler).

Another solution would be to use `ConfigureAwait` on the `GetResponseAsync` task and so the rest of the method wouldn't run on the UI thread, avoiding the deadlock:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I'd also recommend reading Stephen Cleary's [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)